# How to update and save embedded interactive form pdf in server programmatically using JS / Angular?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, interactive

I have an interactive form pdf. I have showed it in iframe. After filling the form when I click the Download PDF button outside the iframe I need to trigger click the Edited button given by iframe when click the download icon. So that my target is to save the edited version of pdf to server programmatically.

I have tried a lot but could not manage to access the edited version of pdf. Please help me if you can. Thanks in advance!

[image: How to access the Edited button in iframe pdf viewer programmatically]